# What is the difference between simple-salesforce and simple_salesforce?

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce

The project is called `simple-salesforce` but the import is from `simple_salesforce`  or I'm missing something?

This means that i do `pip install simple-salesforce` and in my code I do import `simple_salesforce` ?
How does it work? How python knows to do the link between `simple-salesforce` to `simple_salesforce`?

Answer (score 0):

"simple-salesforce" is the name of the module, but since "-" character is an operator in python, they could not use it in variable name, and had to replace it with underscore.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp

Answer (score 0):

The **package name** for pip is `simple-salesforce`. The **module** installed is called `simple_salesforce` (do note that the other spelling would be invalid for python because of the `-`). Python doesn't know the link, pip does. Python only looks for a module called `simple_salesforce` in the configured search locations and imports it, the pip package name is completely irrelevant to python itself (e.g., see package `opencv-python` that installs module `cv2`)